# php upload file does't work because of content

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some Excel files on the server, but unfortunately is doesn't work for some files.

my html code looks like this:

```
<form action="my_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

php file looks like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

and the output

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => speeds.xls
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

It is not file path, naming, size or rights problem but it seems that is a file content problem. I'm saying that is a file content problem because the upload succeeds in some cases. Also if I re-save the Excel file that dind't work in the first place, then the upload file succeed.

How can I solve this problem? Why `$_FILES['file']['error'] = 1`. How to prevent that?

Comment: [_"Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.*

The error code indicates that the file you're trying to upload is larger than the file upload size limit set in php.ini

You can get a full list of these codes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

You need to change the limit in php.ini to allow larger uploads. If you're on a hosted system you might need to check with them hoe to do this: arrangements vary from host to host.